# Permission denied while reading upstream

Tags: nginx

We have deployed our rails application on on Nginx and passenger. Intermittently, pages of application get loaded partially. There is no error in application log, but the Nginx error log shows the following:

```bash
2011/02/14 05:49:34 [crit] 25389#0: *645 open() "/opt/nginx/proxy_temp/2/02/0000000022" 
  failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: x.x.x.x, 
  server: y.y.y.y, request: "GET /signup/procedures?count=0 HTTP/1.1", 
  upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "y.y.y.y", 
  referrer: "http://y.y.y.y/signup/procedures"
```

Comment: You can set the log level to debug: http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

Answer (score 50):

I had the same problem on an NGINX/PHP-FPM setup (php-fpm=improved fcgi for php).

You can find out which user the nginx processes are running as

```
ps aux | grep "nginx: worker process"
```

And then check out if the permissions in your proxy files are correct

```
ls -l /opt/nginx/proxy_temp/
```

In my case, nginx was running as `www-data` and two of the directories in my proxy directory belonged to root.

I don't know how it happened yet, but I fixed it by doing (as root)

```
chown www-data.www-data /opt/nginx/proxy_temp
```

Comment: The best solution!

Comment: Why isn't it accepted yet?

Comment: for those who use #openresty - "chown www-data:www-data -R /usr/local/openresty/nginx/*_temp"

Comment: I stopped my nginx process, renamed the folder to another name, restarted the nginx process and it had created the folder again with correct permissions. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 17):

You probably started with user `root`, then changed it. Now the problem is that the cache folders, i.e.

```bash
/var/cache/nginx/client_temp
/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp
/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp
/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp
/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp
```

are already owned by `root`, so your `nginx` (`www-data` or whatever you're trying to switch to) user can't access them because they have a permission of `700`.

So the solution is easy. Stop nginx, then:

```bash
rm -rf /var/cache/nginx/*
```

or whatever the path is on your distribution and release. Then restart nginx which will re-create these folders with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I've executed the following commands:
```
cd /usr/local
sudo mv fastcgi_temp/ _fastcgi_temp/
sudo nginx -s reload
```
It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Also check the nginx.conf file to make sure you are specifying the correct user AND group.

I had a problem where the permissions on the directory were setup for username/nginx, but the nginx.conf user only specified username. By default, if no group is given to the user directive, it uses the same name as user. So, username/username was trying to access a directory instead of username/nginx. Updating the config fixed my problems.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user

Comment: Can you please post the config you mentioned here?

Answer (score 7):

So I did all of the above and unfortunately for me it was giving me the same error. I am running a rails app packaged into a jar file with torquebox on a centos 6.7 machine with nginx. I battled this for about 3 hours until I found another solution and I hope it helps someone else. 
According to [this article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/) nginx may run on enforcing mode. I just simply changed nginx to permissive mode with

```
setenforce 0
```

With that, the error was gone and I was able to run my application on a staging/production environment.

I was clueless until I found the error on the audit.log

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1444454198.438:466): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=3201 comm="nginx" dest=8080 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_cache_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

I really hope this saves someone the 3 hours I just lost.

Comment: You're not wrong, I don't know why someone vote -1 (shame on him/her). The problem is in RedHat/CentOS based hosts and selinux. One way is setenforce 0 (rude), other way is with setsebool and networking options.

Comment: It helped with CentOS 7.2.

Comment: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24830777/721331

Answer (score 3):

When starting nginx from an unprivileged account the `use_temp_path=off`.

```
proxy_cache_path ... use_temp_path=off;
```

This needed to avoid nginx trying to put the files into the default `proxy_temp_path`.  From the nginx docs:

> The directory for temporary files is set based on the use_temp_path
>   parameter (1.7.10). If this parameter is omitted or set to the value
>   on, the directory set by the proxy_temp_path directive for the given
>   location will be used. If the value is set to off, temporary files
>   will be put directly in the cache directory.

Answer (score -3):

```
chmod 777 /opt/nginx/proxy_temp/
```

I had the same problem and it solved by chmod to that directory.

Comment: chmod 777 is never a good idea.